# How the computer read the program

Tags: scheme, lisp

It is a quite elementary but general question when I am reading SICP. I get puzzled about how the computer
read the program. I understand the computer read the program as a layer or nested system, which means the
lower layer can't read the item from upper layer but it is obvious not true when I encounter this program
in SICP:

```
(define balance 100)
(define (withdraw amount)
        (if (>= balance amount)
            (begin (set! balance(- balance amount))
             balance)
         "Insufficient funds"))
```

As u can see, balance is some item I can treat on the upper layer, while I can see the lower layer program can still read that, so it is wrong, so I am wondering how the computer read the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `withdraw` and `balance` are defined at the *same level* (`balance` is not in an "upper" level), and `balance` was defined *before* `withdraw`, so  it's natural that `withdraw` can "see" `balance`.

The interpreter adds all top-level definitions to the same environment, and one definition can refer to another at the same level as long as it's been previously defined, for example:

```
(define x 10)
(define y (+ 6 x))
```

This applies to nested procedures as well. A nested procedure can "see" all the definitions *above* it. For example, this is valid:

```
(define x 42)

(define (f)      ; f and x are at the same level
  (define (g) x) ; g is in a level below f, but sees x
  (g))

(f)
=> 42
```

In the above example, `g` is *internal* to `f`, nothing outside `f` "sees" `g`, but `g` can "see" all that's above itself.

Comment: a little bit confused, if there is a nested function in withdraw, can the nested function see balance?

Comment: Yes, of course. From any nested procedure you can see everything that's "above" it, including the top-level definitions.

Comment: so it looks I understand it reversely, actually the upper layer can't see the lower layer

Comment: Yes, that's it :) . I added an example showing what I meant.

Comment: @89085731 you might want to skip ahead in the book, and read about "lexical environments", that's all you need to know to understand what's happening.

Comment: where is "lexical environment", I can't find in SICP, sorry

Comment: Sorry, I meant lexical scoping, look for all references in the book's [index](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-38.html#%_index_start).